# how to pagination in Instagram public API (?__a=1)?

Tags: json, instagram, instagram-api

as you know, today Instagram changed his public API, At the past we use for example below URL to get JSON of a page:

```
https://www.instagram.com/ibm/?__a=1
```

we appended `&max_id=[end_cursor]` to the URL and it gives us next page of nodes, but today it does not work, i believe we use something else of `max_id`. any body knows how to get a next page of this API?

Comment: It happened to my application too. My issue was all json structure changed by instagram. The data is not provides by instagram original api so response data structure can be changeable anytime.

Comment: @Ozan , yes , it's so bad. at this moment instagram don't give us permission to access to private API.

Comment: @Ozan , i found this : `https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=472f257a40c653c64c666ce877d59d2b&variables={"id":"","first":12,"after":"[end_cursor]"}` , but i don't know is it safe or not !

Comment: I dont think it is safe..